# Strange value begin inserted at the beginner of query string on Node URL request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-fetch

I'm with a tricky problem here. I have created an API that will fetch some data from an external API. For example:

I have this endpoint on my current api:

`/api/items?q=`

And on the route responsible for that, I have this code:

```js
itemsRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { q } = req.query;

  try {
    const url = new URL(`externalapiurl?q=​${q}`);

    console.log(url);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
  }
});
```

However, if I check my url with `console.log`, the url is always being printed with a espaço encoded, something like: `/search?q=%E2%80%8Biphone'`

If I check the url object from `new URL` on my node terminal, I can see a little space at my q key:

`{ 'q' => '​ iphone' }`

The url object print is bellow:

```
  href:
   'externalapiurl?q=%E2%80%8Bapple%20iphone',
  origin: 'externalapiurl',
  protocol: 'https:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'externalapiurl',
  hostname: 'externalapiurl',
  port: '',
  pathname: 'externalapiurl',
  search: '?q=%E2%80%8Bapple%20iphone',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'q' => ' iphone' },
  hash: '' }
```

Because of that, the request isn't being made correctly. I have already tried encodeURI nd encodeURIComponent, however the problem persist.

PS: This new URL comes from `const URL = require("url").URL;`
And I'm using `node-fetch` to handle the url call.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You can use just node-fetch to make api call instead of using `url`.

Answer (score 1):

I made a copy/paste in my console, and here is what I got :

[image]

As you can see, you have a weird special caracter in your URL. It may not be visible in your text editor, but it appears in the Chrome console. Just try to delete your URL string, and type it again, I think it should work

Comment: Thanks man! That is exactly what I found here. I was coming to here to auto answer my own question. Thank you again! :)